# Is there a way to edit or delete uploaded images on a Trello card?

Tags: trello

When adding an image, sometimes I'll drag in the wrong screenshot or realize I have a better one to add. Would be nice to be able to edit and delete images just like you can with text comments. Know of any way to do that? Or if they're planning on adding that ability in the future?

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit images, but opening a card will display a list of attachments (images, spreadsheets, whatever), each one should have a Delete link next to the right (just below the file size).

[image: Trello Delete option]

Click Delete, click the big red Delete button that pops-up and it's gone.